# Is it possible for tags to be saved in a textbox list input?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, mootools

Please check out this link: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/textboxlist.php

As you can see its a textbox list input.

If you enter a tag but then refresh the page the tag disappears.

Is it possible to make the same textbox list input but have each tag saved so when the page is refreshed its still there?

I have been trying to find an answer but Im unsure of what I am looking for.

Comment: you want to look into AJAX, when the tag is added you can submit the data to the server - jQuery offers ajax functionality. Happy reading.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there an example of this anywhere? The only demos I can find dont save the inputted tag

Comment: mootools also offers ajax functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use...

- [JavaScript cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
- [HTML5 `localStorage`](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/html5_local_storage.htm)
- AJAX to send a complete list of the current tags to the server every time they're updated, and then have the server...

  - store the tags in a database
  - set a cookie
  - start/update a session
- Any time the textarea is updated, submit the form to the server, choose from the above, and reload the page